# javascript to hide all clients that do not correspond with contents of text input search box

Tags: javascript

I have a page that pulls a list of my clients from a database, I want to add a search box that dynamically, without reloading page, hides all of the clients that do not match the text typed in the box.

Is this possible with javascript, or is there another method I should try?

My list is coded as such pulling the info from a database.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=client&cid=125">Client Name</a></li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <li><a href="index.php?pg=client&cid=111">Client Name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, on keyup you need to show all then hide elements whose contents don't have a partial or full match of the string in the input field if the input field is not empty.

Comment: You should show an attempt, SO is not write some code for me http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ Takes about 4-5 lines with `jQuery`

Answer (score 3):

JQuery makes it easier for you Here it is in action http://jsfiddle.net/PUNaM/

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
<input id="filter" />    
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    $("ul>li").hide();
    $("ul>li:contains("+this.value+")").show();
})
```

Comment: Upvote even though you're fishing for the OP (because they never posted any effort). Since you already gave it away, let me put it in a jsfiddle

Comment: @JuanMendes, how nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're willing to use jQuery.

First, you need to have some way to reference your list and your textbox via javascript. I'll use an id as an example, but it might be anything.

```
<input type="text" id="search-box" />

<ul id="clients-list">
  <!-- clients list here -->
</ul>
```

Then, on the javascript, you can listen for the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

```
$("#search-box").on("keyup", filterClients);
```

That will make the `filterClients` function be called when the user releases a key. There are many ways to define that, but I will go the simple way:

```
function filterClients(event) {
  var $search = $(event.target);
  var text = $search.val();

  var $clients = $("#clients-list li");
  $clients.each(function() {
    var $client = $(this);
    var clientName = $client.text();

    var searchMatchesName = clientName.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) >= 0;

    if(searchMatchesName) {
      $client.show();
    } else {
      $client.hide();
    }
  });
}
```

This is not the most efficient or more fancy way to do this, but should be enough to get you started.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u5WS3/